XLA can't find algorithm for grouped convolutions with Conv3D
I have a Conv3D layer in my model. It produces correct results, however, each time I run it Tensorflow throws me the following warning:
W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/gpu/gpu_conv_algorithm_picker.cc:727] None of the algorithms provided by cuDNN heuristics worked; trying fallback algorithms.  Conv: (f32[8,64,64,64,128]{3,2,1,4,0}, u8[0]{0}) custom-call(f32[8,64,64,64,512]{3,2,1,4,0}, f32[1,1,1,256,128]{2,1,0,3,4}), window={size=1x1x1}, dim_labels=b012f_012io->b012f, feature_group_count=2, custom_call_target="__cudnn$convForward", backend_config="{\"conv_result_scale\":1,\"activation_mode\":\"0\",\"side_input_scale\":0}"

Minimal reproducible example:
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import layers

conv_layer = layers.Conv3D(
    kernel_size=1,
    filters=128,
    groups=2,
)

batch_size = 8
layer_input = tf.random.normal((batch_size, 64, 64, 64, 512))
output = conv_layer(layer_input)
print(output.shape)

Interestingly, if I don't use grouped convolutions the warning disappears. However, I need grouped convolutions due to computational constraints.
If I increase the batch size to 16, it fails completely with the following error:
Failed to determine best cudnn convolution algorithm for:
%cudnn-conv = (f32[16,64,64,64,128]{3,2,1,4,0}, u8[0]{0}) custom-call(f32[16,64,64,64,512]{3,2,1,4,0} %copy, f32[1,1,1,256,128]{2,1,0,3,4} %copy.1), window={size=1x1x1}, dim_labels=b012f_012io->b012f, feature_group_count=2, custom_call_target="__cudnn$convForward", metadata={op_type="Conv3D" op_name="Conv3D" source_file="/home/ssh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional/base_conv.py" source_line=225}, backend_config="{\"conv_result_scale\":1,\"activation_mode\":\"0\",\"side_input_scale\":0}"

Original error: UNKNOWN: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED
in tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(3520): 'op' CUDNN_BACKEND_OPERATION: cudnnFinalize Failed

I am wondering how this warning affects the performance of the model (it's very important to me) and is there a workaround to aid XLA for picking an appropriate algorithm.
I'm using Tensorflow 2.9.1 and cuDNN 8.1.0.
